# PHP backend in Spotify App not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spotify

I'm trying to make a spotify app that takes in user information and sends it to an SQL database. However, I don't want this to be done using ajax since I want the submission of the information to move the user to a new page while the information is posted to the database in the background.

Here's my code so far:

```
function complete2() {
var name = document.getElementById("inputname").value;
var form = '<form action="http://site.net/dbconnect.php" method="post" style="display:none">' + '<input type="text" name="name" value="' + name + '">' + '</form>';
$('body').append(form);
$(form).submit();
}

 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
<form id = "submitform" name = "submitform" action = "index.html" method = "POST" onsubmit = "complete2();" >
Name: <input type = "text" id = "inputname"> <br>
<input type = "submit" value = "Create">
</form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: cant you just send a header redirect back from the DB in php like `header("Location: sp://APP_ID/thenextpage.html")`... I assume Spotify is essentially just an HTML client in this respect and will understand the header. In that case you would just post as normal, perhaps sending along the location you want to redirect to so that nothing is hardcoded on the external server.

Comment: Spotify Apps don't allow you to use any PHP, so unfortunately I don't think that'd work

Comment: Ummm you wouldnt be using php from within spotify... you would be doing the same thing youre doing now - running php on the external server which you POST a request to.

Comment: I see what you were saying, I misunderstood. I'm still getting a problem though. I'm getting: Not allowed to load local resource

Comment: Is this from the php server or from the spotify client?

Comment: Spotify client, (error is given to me in the inspector, the actual app just stays on the same page). And I've already added the site in the required permissions part of the manifest.json

Comment: hmm ok... it was worth a shot... posting an answer below

Comment: You should use ajax or not to post or get data (for example JSON) on remote server, but don't forget to add the server to manifest (RequiredPermissions section) and reload application. You can't redirect spotify outside of the application. But you can push data to php server and get data from php server, example : $.getJSON(PATH, function(data) { } );

Answer (score 1):

So i know you dont want to use AJAX but if you want to load a differnt html file in your local app and Spotify doesnt respect a location header to an internal resource then youre stuck with ajax. However you can make it simialr to what would happen with a standard post something like:

```
$(function(){
  $('#submitform').submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $.post(
         $(this).attr('action'), 
         {'inputname': $(this).find('#inputname').val()}, 
         function(){ window.location.href = 'sp://yourapp/nextpage.html'; }
     );
  });
});
```

Comment: this still is taking me to the PHP page as opposed to the next spotify page. As well, the POST isn't working either since I'm testing this out and it is adding null values into the database

Comment: I got the database part working (changed it from a POST to a GET and took the quotes off 'inputname') but the page redirection still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample to get data

```
$.getJSON("http://www.exx.com/getjsondata.php", function (data) {
parsetheresponse(data) ; 
}
```

Here is a sample to post data (still in JSON)

```
$.post("http://www.exx.com/postdataspotify.php", { albumname: "test", username: "test2" });
```

Hope it will help.

Don't forget to put http://www.exx.com in manifest file.